# Is there any way to find out maximum value from property in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, max

I have a nodes where property maximum value is 772 but when I try with maximum value it doesn't show.

[image: Maximum value]

I have been try with Max cyper query is output is different also not showing in graph form.

```
MATCH (n:citation) RETURN max(n.Name)
```

[image: output result]

Is there any way I have also try with DESC option but not working.

```
MATCH (n:citation) RETURN n.Name order by n.Name DESC
```

[image: order by Descending]

It's showing maximum number like
1
10
100
2
20
3
35

so it will not take normal maximum value 100 but showing 35 is maximum..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotation marks in your query results indicate that this property is stored as a string. The `order by` is therefore alphabetical, not numeric. Try casting the results (or the property itself) [to an int](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger).